# More than one notifications are not grouping or not shown separately

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am newbie about android programing. I am trying to implement sample codes to my project that as [link](https://github.com/morinel/gcmpush/blob/master/src/nl/vanvianen/android/gcm/GCMModule.java).

When I send to my device more than one notification from my remote server successfully, current notification disappears from android notification area when new one comes. More than one notifications are not grouping or not shown separately.

Should I focus to where for solving this behaviour? Thank you in advance.

My server php codes as below;

```
$Message = array
                (
                    'message'   => $ArrPushMessage["Message"],
                    'title'     => $ArrPushMessage["Title"],


                );
                $Fields = array
                (
                    'registration_ids'  => $RegistrationIds,
                    'data'          => $Message
                );

                $Headers = array
                (
                    'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_ACCESS_KEY,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                );

                $Curl = curl_init();
                curl_setopt( $Curl,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
                curl_setopt( $Curl,CURLOPT_POST, true );
                curl_setopt( $Curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $Headers );
                curl_setopt( $Curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
                curl_setopt( $Curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
                curl_setopt( $Curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $Fields ) );
                $GoogleResult = json_decode(curl_exec($Curl),true);
                curl_close( $Curl );
```

Server result as below;

```
Array ( [multicast_id] => 4.9523621355218E+18 [success] => 1 [failure] => 0 [canonical_ids] => 0 [results] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [message_id] => 0:1458493214513473%2d713a4ef9fd7ecd ) ) ) Array ( [multicast_id] => 8.963309427397E+18 [success] => 1 [failure] => 0 [canonical_ids] => 0 [results] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [message_id] => 0:1458493214608687%2d713a4ef9fd7ecd ) ) )
```

Comment: are you using unique id for your every single notification ?

Comment: @RachitSolanki thanks your for your comment. I edited my question with my server side code.

Comment: Check in your android code where you  Add a notification
      NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      manager.notify(uniqueid++, builder.build());